Strongswan- Configuration required from mutiple network connectivity
On-Prem -------------------------- AWS ------------------------------ GCP
(192.168.x.x)                   (172.10.x.x)                     (10.10.x.x)
(Strongswan VM)
Hi Friends
I have configured Strongswan on ec2 instance on AWS. I can access GCP Servers(10.10.x.x) from AWS (172.10.x.x) as well as from On-Prem (192.168.x.x).
I can access On-Prem (192.168.x.x) from AWS (172.10.x.x). Also AWS (172.10.x.x) from GCP (10.10.x.x).
But I am not able to access On-prem(192.168.x.x) from GCP (10.10.x.x)
I have also configured masquerading
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
Please suggest
Thanks

Where have you set up masquerading?

masquerading setup On EC2 VM

The onprem lacks a route back to the VPN stuff.

Can you please help me with the route which is needed at on-prem?

Hi!!! Waiting for reply ...
